# displaying whole world map with topoJSON and D3

Tags: maps, d3.js

first of all I'm totally new to this two libraries (which I believe are awesome), so sorry if this sounds like a stupid question. I would like to display the whole world using d3 + topoJSON. I'm following [this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) tutorial to do so. I downloaded both the files but when it comes to using `ogr2ogr` I avoid filtering for England + Ireland to get the whole world. I then follow the tutorial to print the map but in the end I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined` on line 1 of the optimised topoJSON library :-).

Now, I'm pretty sure I did something wrong with the conversion when calling `ogr2ogr`, but I can't figure which is the correct filter to apply to get the whole map. Is somebody with a little bit more experience willing to help?

Thanks

P.S.
If I follow the tutorial using the UK map, it shows it correctly, so I really think it's something related to `ogr2ogr` conversion.

EDIT:

These are the commands used to convert the maps and merge them:
`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON subunits.json ne_10m_admin_0_map_subunits.shp`, then I used `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON places.json ne_10m_populated_places.shp` and finally to merge them: `topojson --id-property su_a3 -p NAME=name -p name -o world.json subunits.json places.json`.

Comment: could you post your ogr2ogr commands as you used as well as the topojson commands you used

Comment: Sure, let me add them to the question.